# Cadena que contenga '@' con wildcard

Tags: c#, ms-word, microsoft-office

Quize buscar algo con la función `range.Find.Execute()`, ya que necesito encontrar todas las palabras que inicien con un arroba `@` y las *wildcards* que probe fueron:

```
(@)*
(^064)*
```

Pero ninguna me sirvió. ¿Con cuál puedo encontrar este tipo de cadenas?

Actualización:

```
private void Findvar(Word.Range Range, object findText){
    var rng = Range;    
    rng.Collapse();
    object saveas = true;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    while (rng.Find.Execute(findText, ref missing, ref missing, ref saveas, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing))
    {
        //rng.Font.Bold = 1;
        rng.Text = " "+rng.Text.Substring(3);
        Findvar(rng, findText);
    }
}
```

Esta es mi función, recibe una cadena y un rango y hace algo, en este caso inserta el mismo texto encontrado pero cortado.

Comment: Y el código? Así clarificas tu pregunta y te podemos ayudar mejor

Comment: Para indicar que algo empieza por `@`  deberías decir `^@`.

Comment: si uso solo `^@` me lanza excepcion`^  no es un carácter especial válido para el cuadro Buscar o no se admite cuando está activada la casilla Usar caracteres comodín.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que buscar `\@` pero no se puede poner directamente pues marca error de

> Secuencia de escape no reconocida

Por lo que una solución rápida fue esta:

```
string a = "(\\@)*";
Findvar(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range, a);
```

Así puedo encontrar cualquier cadena que empiece con `@`

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como válida ✓ una vez que hayan pasado 24 o 48 hrs :)